# Suddenly "no connections are available" on windows 7 sp1

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I've tried almost everything around to fix the lack of wireless connection on my laptop.
To help anyone who's reading this out here's a list of what I've tried:

-Reseting the router

-Checking if the wlan is working (It is, i'm actually writing this on another laptop next to the failing one).

-Uninstalling/Re-installing my wireless card Ralink RT3290 drivers
-Installing updated drivers

-Disabling the ability to power down the wireless card to save power

-Enabling maximum performance on the wireless card in power options

-Disabling firewall

-Enabling "Turn on network discovery" in advanced sharing settings, for home and public network profiles

-Disabling/Enabling keyboard shortcut for airplane mode

Comment: Does the device appears in the device manager as normal?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I couldn't update the drivers.

Comment: May be a hardware failure - if you have an opportunity try to connect with external (USB) WiFi adapter.

Comment: Indeed. As @MarianD commented it can be and hardware failure and still the device looks normal in device manager. But are you absolutely sure about disabling "airplane mode"? Also it takes some time to scan for networks after coming from that mode, have you waited long enough?

Comment: Tried a usb wlan pen, and everything is fine. I confirm it was a hardware failure